# how to restart window service

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

i want to restart window service named "Spooler" i did following code , but no luck, Any body has any idea about what is going on wrong?
code is

```
using System.ServiceProcess;

ServiceController service = new ServiceController("Spooler");

if ((service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)) ||
    (service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)))
{
    service.Start();
}
else
{
    service.Stop();
    service.Start();
}
```

exception is

> "System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot start service Spooler on
>   computer '.'. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An instance
>   of the service is already running
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
>
> at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start()
>
> at servicerestart.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   in D:\samplecodes\servicerestart\servicerestart\Form1.cs:line 33"

Comment: `but no luck` is not a very precise problem description. Could you perform a more specific description of the problem not involving luck or God but involving concrete error messages or undesired behavior.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov i have updated my question

Answer (score 9):

You must wait after stopping the service before starting it once again using the [`WaitForStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w52kaf2y.aspx) method:

```
else
{
    service.Stop();
    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
    service.Start();
    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
}
```

Comment: it looks like it will work, but i dont see that service is stopping and starting in service applet(SCM). Do we have any mechanism to stop fast and start immeadiately?

Comment: No, that's the correct way to start and stop a service in .NET. You might also wait after the service has started.

Comment: i dont think after .Start(); method ,there will be a ServiceControllerStatus.Started method. There is a compilation error

Comment: Yeah, that should be `Running` instead of `Started`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: still in applet window i am not able to see sevice is stopped and started. may be everything going fast?? is there any mechanism to see whether serivce stoppped and started, from registry or anywhere?? from eventlog i am not able to see it

Comment: It's normal that you don't see it, it may happen fast and you might not have refreshed the window fast enough. You could put a breakpoint in your code just at the `service.Start();` line and not execute it until you see that the service has stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I think the probelm is that you require administrator privilege to start and stop service, this is why you have to give rights needed.

to do this go to change the identity of applicationpool in ISS to LocalSystem.

Hope this help